# Python - can we use value of a variable as a part of the name of a different variable

Tags: python, variables

I want to see if it is possible to use value of a variable as part of the name for another variable.

```
i = 23
test_[i] = "potato"
print test_23
```

How can i use the value of a variable as part of the name of a different variable ?

Comment: No, you can't really do that. Someone may be able to warp the language for an answer, but you want a dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 1):

The technical answer is yes, but I would strongly advise you that you definitely just want to use a dictionary instead. If for some reason you still want to you can use the `exec` function to do it. For example:

```
i = 23
exec("test_" + str(i) + " = \"potato\"")

# you can use 'test_23' here
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a dictionary:

```
>>> i = 23
>>> test = {i: "potato"}
>>> test[23]
'potato'
```

Answer (score 0):

hm... As you can generate code and then execute with `eval`, may be you can use something like this:

```
x_0 = 0
x_1 = 1
x_2 = 2


for i in range(3):
   y = eval('x_%i' % i) + 1
   print(y)
```